# Howler sound does not resume on IOS after page refresh

Tags: javascript, ios, howler.js

I have an HTML5 web app that uses Howler for the sound engine. When testing on Safari browser on a real ios device I am having trouble with pausing/unpausing of sounds. we have an event that fires when the browser loses focus, I pause the sound when it is fired and resume it on another event when focus is returned.

This works perfectly on the first visit to the page, thereafter though no sound can be heard on the page. I have dumped the soundEngine object to see if it's settings and context is still intact, and they are, however on the second visit or after a page refresh the sound does not resume.

The sound will not play until I have performed a cache reset on the browser at which point it will work for that page visit but not subsequent visits.

I have tried pausing/unpausing, stopping/resuming, setting volumes, setting the _globalPause flags, adding onplayerror callbacks to the objects setup.

```
onPauseHandler: function () {
    console.log("The pause hanlder has been called.")
    if (soundEngine.hasAmbience()) {
        soundEngine.setAmbienceVol(0);
    }
    if (soundEngine.hasSFX()) {
        soundEngine.setSFXVol(0);
    }
},
onResumeHandler: function () {
    console.log("The resume hanlder has been called.")
    if (soundEngine.hasAmbience()) {
        soundEngine.setAmbienceVol(1);
    }
    if (soundEngine.hasSFX()) {
        soundEngine.setSFXVol(1);    
    }
}
```

The above code is obviously only a single version of the fixes I've tried, as mentioned above. soundEngine is just a wrapper for Howler.